# How can I align content in a div with content outside of it in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

So I have this section which ocupies the whole width of the screen but the text in it is contained in a container and aligns properly.

The section below that one is divided in two columns, and im interested in putting a text in the left column that aligns with the text above it but so far have been unable to do so.

This is the result I'm getting:

[image]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center bg-primary" style="min-height: 450px">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="">TITLE TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="">
  <div class="subhead bg-primary">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm bg-secondary" style="min-height: 400px">
        <div class="container">
          <h3>TITLE</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm bg-warning" style="min-height: 400px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And the HTML I'm currently stuck with(The css was just added in the HTML for testing)

Tank you for any help provided and if you need anything more please just tell me.

Comment: In bootstrap you should use col-sm-1, col-sm-2...12, col-md-1...12 or col-lg-1...12 for dividing space into columns in your case i would set top div to be col-md-12 for example and bottom two col-md-6, then you can simply set h1 width as needed also using col-md and then to align bottom you would also use col-md. You will have to play around a bit to get it right these col classes are % width so they should look ok on most res.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="">
  <div class="row bg-primary" style="min-height: 450px">
    <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">TITLE TEXT</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="">
  <div class="subhead bg-primary">
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 400px">
      <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center bg-secondary">
        <div class="container">
        <h3 class="text-center">TITLE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-warning"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Well, that just centers the text inside the div and I want it aligned with the text above it. Thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.text-to-center{ display:flex}
h1,h3{ margin:auto;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="">
  <div class="row bg-primary" style="min-height: 450px">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="container text-to-center">
      
        <h1 class="text-center">TITLE TEXT</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="">
  <div class="subhead bg-primary">
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 400px">
      <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center bg-secondary">
        <div class="container text-to-center">
        <h3 class="text-center">TITLE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-warning"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```